# Align an item bottom to another only if enough space available / no overlaps

Tags: android

In my xml-layout I have a text aligned to the bottom of an imageview with align_bottm.

This causes overlaps, if there is too much text above it. How it is possible to

a) align the text to an element if there is enough space
and b) put it below the other texts if there is not enough space to align with the imageview?

Especiially in xml.

Thanks,
best regards